# Assembly functions FPU with c

Tags: c, assembly, fpu

So I am writing some C with Assembly in AT&T. I've got small problem right now, because when I call first function that is f_float with float parameter, parameter is loaded from stack and returned value is proper. But with the second call f_double with double parameter, the value isn't loading from stack. I'm on linux Mint 17.1, gcc version 4.9.2(Ubuntu4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04). Any advices?

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

float f_float(float);
double f_double(double);

int main()

{
float a, f_result;
double b, d_result;

printf("\nInsert float number:  ");
scanf("%f", &a); 

printf("\nInsert double number: ");
scanf("%lf", &b);

f_result = f_float(a);
d_result = f_double(b);
printf("\nResult of float with f function: %f", f_result);
printf("\nResult of double with f function: %lf", d_result);

return 0;
}
```

functions.s

```
s_precision = 0x007f
d_precision = 0x027f

#(x^2)/(sqrt(x^2 +1) +1)

.globl f_float
.type f_float, @function

f_float:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $2, %esp

finit   

movl $s_precision, -2(%ebp)
fldcw -2(%ebp)
flds 8(%ebp)            
fmul %st(0)
fld1
fadd %st(1), %st(0)
fsqrt
fld1
fsubr %st(1), %st(0)

movl %ebp, %esp
pop %ebp
ret

.globl f_double
.type f_double, @function

f_double:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $2, %esp

finit   

movl $d_precision, -2(%ebp)
fldcw -2(%ebp)
fldl 8(%ebp)            
fmul %st(0)
fld1
fadd %st(1), %st(0)
fsqrt
fld1
fsubr %st(1), %st(0)

movl %ebp, %esp
pop %ebp
ret
```

Comment: Advice: don't write whole functions in assembler. Use the `asm` keyword with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). And it is ABI and processor specific, so you should edit your question to tell more about your compiler, processor, and operating system. Also, try coding some stuff in C and look at the generated assembler code (e.g. with `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`)

Comment: That's part of my homework. Need to do that.

Comment: `subl $2, %esp` is very bad, do not misalign the stack pointer. Also `movl $d_precision, -2(%ebp)` writes 4 bytes to 2 bytes of allocated space overwriting saved `ebp` on the stack. The part about the `double` looks right, use a debugger. PS: seems to work fine here, what input did you try?

Comment: Changing `movl $*_precision` to `movw $*_precision` resolved problem. That was mistake of course, but thought that it will overwrite the data left on stack later on. Anyway, problem soved. Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `movl $*_precision` to `movw $*_precision` resolved problem. That was mistake of course, but thought that it will overwrite the data left on stack later on. Anyway, problem soved. Thanks to everyone for help. – Robs